# Como adicionar opacidade no menu do bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estou começando agora a mexer tanto com site quanto com bootstrap, estou utilizando o wordpress tbm. Ok a minha duvida é a seguinte, eu adicionei o menu padrão do bootstrap em meu site, e deixei ele fixo no topo tbm, gostaria de saber agora como eu que faço para mexer na opacidade dele, para que quando eu descer o site ele n fico sobrepondo o conteúdo do site, dando assim para ver parte do conteúdo mesmo com o menu fixo.

Procurei e ainda não achei, gostaria de saber se é através do próprio HTML que da para fazer isso, ou vou ter que fazer isso através dos css msm...

Código do menu.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você adicionar opacity na classe navbar não da certo?

```
.navbar
{
   opacity: 0.7;
}
```

O bootstrap em si não possui um helper para opacidade, faça pelo CSS mesmo

### EDIT:

Para o menu ficar opaco apenas quando você desce a página, tente fazer assim:
Criar uma classe no css:

```
.opaque
{
   opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Deixar a navbar fixada no topo:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

E utilizar esse jQuery, para que, quando você rolar a página, ele adicione a classe opaque para a navbar, e quando voltar ao topo, ele remova:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("opaque");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("opaque");
    }
});
```

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO, deu muito certo, e vlw pelas dicas ^^